# The Mac OS X package installer doesn’t display the file system partition on which Mac OS X is installed

Tags: macos, installation, partitioning, osx-mountain-lion

When a package, in a `.pkg` file, needs to be installed on a Mac OS X system, the package installer provided with the system is used. At some point in the installation of any package, it asks on which file system partition it should install the package. On my system, it used to show the partition on which Mac OS X is installed, which is called “Macintosh HD”, but it does not anymore due to reasons I am unaware of, and instead only shows the two recovery partitions both called “Recovery HD”; this effectively makes me unable to install anything using a package installer. Furthermore, the system partition is also absent from the choices available in the Mavericks installer, which means this problem also prevents me from upgrading my system from Mountain Lion to Mavericks.

I have told the disk utility to repair the hard drive, but it hasn’t found any problem. I have also wanted to repair the system partition, but it was absent from the list of partitions in the disk utility. I was later able to have it displayed by enabling the disk utility’s debug mode and although the repair option was grayed, I was able to run a verification that found no problem and to repair the permissions.

Furthermore, the “Partition” tab of the disk utility, when the hard drive is selected, claims the place where the system partition should be is actually 207.91 GB of free space. There are some other partitions I have previously used to run a Debian system, but I have since then erased them and they are now empty partitions.

Finally, I am unable to change the partition layout at all from the “Partition” tab of the disk utility when the hard drive is selected: every time I attempt to delete a partition or to apply a change, it tells me the change asked is too small and refuses to perform it.

My current system is Mac OS X 10.8.5 running on a Mac mini.

Comment: I'd use Disk Utility to run "Repair Disk" on both the hard drive device itself (to repair the partition table) and on the main boot partition (to repair the HFS+ filesystem structures). I might also run a "Repair Permissions" on the main boot partition as well.

Comment: @Spiff I have attempted what you have suggested and added information about the results to the question, along with other information.

Comment: Can you post the output of `sudo gpt -v show -l /dev/disk0` ? That's a fairly definitive statement about the state of your disk's GUID Partition Table (GPT). It sounds like your GPT got borked by Debian. Also, the output of `sudo fdisk /dev/disk0` would also be useful, to see what your Protective Master Boot Record (PMBR) says. On GPT disks (Intel-based Mac boot disks are GPT), GPT is authoritative, but there's also usually a "Protective MBR" to tell MBR-based tools that the whole disk is allocated, in hopes that such non-GPT-aware tools won't try to erase or repartition the drive.

Comment: @Spiff I had to boot on the recovery utility from the Internet and to unmount all partitions to be able to run the command and get another message than “Resource busy”; I also had to replace `/dev/disk0` by `disk0` for the `gpt` command. [Results and session log](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/1d9503650d20b935da81).

Comment: I forgot that those tools had changed slightly between OS versions. On your version, you may have been able to add `-r` (read only) to the `gpt` command to get it to work on a busy volume. Well, the good news is, your PMBR looks correct. Your GPT looks a bit messy, but possibly correct. I'd need to see the output of the same `gpt` command, but without the `-l`, so we can see if your ~193GiB partition is still marked with the HFS+ GUID, or if it's accidentally been marked with the GUID for a different partition type. So `sudo gpt -rv show disk0`.

Comment: @Spiff [The results](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/e072088fc548f4b2bd2d) don’t look very different (I think the partition names were replaced by unique identifiers?), but I was able to run it without using the recovery utility.

Comment: Those GUIDs (Globally Unique IDentifiers) tell you the partition type. It's clear now that your ~193GiB main volume is marked as an "Apple_Boot" partition type (read: a recovery volume that most tools are supposed to hide, even though it's actually HFS+ inside) rather than being marked as a normal, visible HFS+ volume. It's clear that several other partitions on your drive are incorrectly marked as well. Fixing this means editing your partition table, which is dangerous to do without a full block-by-block backup of your entire device (all partitions, including partition tables).

Comment: @Spiff Do you have any suggestion concerning this process (i.e. backing up the device, restoring it if something goes wrong and fixing the partition table)? I suppose there are (command-line) tools to do this, but I do not know them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, your GPT is all jacked up. A lot of your partitions are marked with the wrong partition types. Your PMBR looks perfect though, so that's good.

Let's look at your GPT (Make sure to make your window W-I-D-E or scroll horizontally to see the "should be" column):

```
      start       size  index  contents - "Label"                   type                     should be
          0          1         PMBR
          1          1         Pri GPT header
          2         32         Pri GPT table
         34          6         
         40     409600      1  GPT part - "EFI system partition"    EFI system partition
     409640  404390464      2  GPT part - "Macintosh HD"            Apple_Boot               HFS+
  404800104    1269544      3  GPT part - "Recovery HD"             EFI system partition     Apple_Boot
  406069648    1269544      4  GPT part - "Recovery HD"             HFS+                     Apple_Boot (or just delete it)
  407339192    1269536      5  GPT part - "Recovery HD"             HFS+                     Apple_Boot (or just delete it)
  408608728         40         
  408608768  279976563      6  GPT part - "Ubuntu"                  Apple_Boot               Linux filesystem data?
  688585331       1421         
  688586752     974848      7  GPT part - ""                        EFI system partition     Not sure? Maybe just delete it?
  689561600   13410304      8  GPT part - "Apple_HFS_Untitled_6"    HFS+
  702971904     262144         
  703234048    5597184      9  GPT part - "Apple_HFS_Untitled_5"    HFS+
  708831232     262144         
  709093376     780288     10  GPT part - "Apple_HFS_Untitled_4"    HFS+
  709873664  258428928     11  GPT part - "Apple_HFS_Untitled_3"    HFS+
  968302592     262144         
  968564736    7946248     12  GPT part - "Apple_HFS_Untitled_2"    HFS+
  976510984     262151         
  976773135         32         Sec GPT table
  976773167          1         Sec GPT header
```

So it looks like your partitions at indexes 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, and 7 are all marked as the wrong partition types in the GPT, and maybe some of them can be deleted if you don't have any valuable data on them. I'm also not sure why you have a bunch of smallish HFS+ partitions, like the one at index 10 that's just 390 MB (381 MiB). Did you put those there intentionally or know what they are and what's on them? Or are they also part of the mystery of this strangely messed up partition table?

I should state that I don't know much about how Debian likes to partition disks, especially on Mac hardware. I know that once upon a time, Linux distros on Windows PCs with GPT used a Windows partition type for Linux filesystems, but I think that old method is falling out of favor today. Perhaps its possible that Debian used Apple-style partition type markers in the GPT but then "on the inside" used them as linux filesystem and swap partitions?

## How to fix

One way to fix this would be to use the `gpt` command to remove the partition table entries that have the wrong type, then re-add them again with the correct type. This is tricky work, and you have a great chance of losing an entire partition or everything on the drive if you make a mistake.

But it would go something like this:

Remove the "bad" entry for "Macintosh HD" that had type Apple_Boot (that GUID starting 426...):

```
sudo gpt remove -b 409640 -s 404390464 -i 2 -t 426F6F74-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC disk0
```

Add a "good" entry for it, this time with type HFS+ (that GUID starting 484...):

```
sudo gpt add    -b 409640 -s 404390464 -i 2 -t 48465300-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC disk0
```

Now label it "Macintosh HD" again:

```
sudo gpt label  -b 409640 -s 404390464 -i 2 -l "Macintosh HD" disk0
```

Note that in the "remove" and "label" commands, I'm selecting the partition in more than one way. That's me being extra-careful to avoid typos; if all three selector types don't match, I don't want the command to work, because it means I made a typo.

Note that you'll have to do these commands while booted from some other device, so the disk you're editing won't be busy. Be very careful with the starting/beginning block and size/length numbers. **Edit partition tables at your own risk. Have a full backup (and TEST YOUR BACKUP) of everything you care about before editing your partition table.**

Comment: The untitled HFS+ partitions are the partitions previously used to run Debian that I have since erased with the disk utility and at the same time changed the format of to HFS+. I would delete them along with all the others you suggest to delete (except the one at index 7, which I have no idea about) if the disk utility tool didn’t tell me the change asked is too small. The extraneous recovery partitions are from the reinstallation and the attempt to install Mavericks, I believe. Index 6 can be deleted as well, since there is no data on it that I want to keep.

Comment: Okay, I added some info on how to fix it. Given your latest comment, if I were you'd I'd back up everything I care about off of that one partition you care about ("Macintosh HD" at index 2), then test my backup, then boot from something else and run the gpt commands I gave. Then I'd see if that worked (by booting from it), and if that worked, I'd probably reboot *again* so I could use GPT to do the rest of the clean up (change the recovery partition at index 3 from EFI to Apple_Boot, then delete all the later partitions from the map).

Comment: There is no data in any partition that I actually care about keeping, even on index 2, since all my important data is on the cloud or backed up already. Index 7 might be [rEFInd](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/), which I used to run Debian and Ubuntu, so it can probably be deleted too. That leaves me with 1, 2 and 3. 1 is fine, 3 is not really important since the recovery utility can boot from the Internet anyway. Thus, the problem here seems to be to delete everything except 1, 2 and 3 and change the type of 2 to HFS+.

Comment: @RastusVernon I agree with your last comment. In fact, come to think of it, I might even just plain delete the recovery partition at index 3, because when you upgrade to Mavericks, the Mavericks installer will probably create whatever recovery partition it needs.

Comment: This seems to have worked. I have executed the three commands and the disk utility now shows the Macintosh HD partition without debug mode; I haven’t yet tried to install a package or Mavericks, but I will do so as soon as I have cleaned up what remains to be cleaned up.

Comment: Great! Thanks for the followup. It's always nice to know that I helped.